# How to get Google Street View panoramas on the same street as the requested address?

Tags: javascript, geocoding, google-maps-api

The Google Maps API geocodes an address to a point. I can use that point to find the nearest panorama (street view) image. I can then determine the heading based on the two points and show the panorama pointed at the right house.

The problem is that in some cases such as corner lots, the closest panorama might be on a different street. For example, a house with an address of 654 NW 4th Street is on the corner of 4th and Greenwood.  The closest panorama is showing on Greenwood instead of 4th so I get a picture of the side of the house instead of the house.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Is there a way to get a list of panorama's so that I can find one that is on the correct street?

It's odd because the correct panorama shows if using Google directly. E.g.:

[`https://maps.google.com/maps?q=654+NW+4TH+ST,+REDMOND,+OR+97756`](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=654%20NW%204TH%20ST,%20REDMOND,%20OR%2097756)

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shadc/q79Yn/) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Looks like this has been asked and answered before on StackOverflow: [Why are some street-view images from the wrong angle?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16111626/386205) Note, however, that one commentator suggests that this problem is a recent regression.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this work-around does the same thing.  The DirectionsService requires a lat/long start and end and I'm passing in the geocoded address as the end. The result tells the user to drive to the side street.  You can see it here [http://jsfiddle.net/shadc/RsaKw/](http://jsfiddle.net/shadc/RsaKw/).  The end point is on Greenwood, not 4th.

Comment: I see. You might want to post this to the [Google Maps API issues list](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list).